# Connecting to Slack channels with Jabber

Tags: jabber

I can connect with Slack through `jabber` and chat with individual users, but I can't join channels. There are some instructions [here](https://dbcorp.slack.com/account/gateways), but I don't know which `jabber` commands to use. I've tried `jabber-muc-join` and `jabber-groupchat-join`, but neither of those seem to work. I use `conference.name.xmpp.slack.com` for the server name.

Comment: start a jabber call in slack with slack command: /jabbercall

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Slack XMPP server doesn't provide correct information about chat rooms in response to an information discovery query.  Could you try the following function and see if `M-x jabber-join-slack-room` lets you join the room?

```el
(defun jabber-join-slack-room (jc group nickname)
  (interactive
   (let ((account (jabber-read-account))
         (group (jabber-read-jid-completing "group: ")))
     (list account group (jabber-muc-read-my-nickname account group))))
  ;; The Slack server does not return a proper disco result:
  ;;
  ;; 1. The disco response has no 'from' attribute.  It should be
  ;; copied from the 'to' attribute of the request, so that the client
  ;; can correlate the request and the response.
  ;;
  ;; 2. The response doesn't contain an identity of "conference",
  ;; which jabber.el looks for to confirm that this is in fact a
  ;; conference room.  (It would be confusing to try to "join" one of
  ;; your contacts.)
  ;;
  ;; 3. The disco response doesn't contain the feature
  ;; "muc_passwordprotected", so jabber.el doesn't know that it needs
  ;; to provide a password.
  ;;
  ;; Therefore, let's seed the correct information into the disco
  ;; cache before joining the room.
  (jabber-disco-got-info
   jc `(iq ((type . "result")
             (from . ,group)
             (id . "emacs-iq-21272.27175.175195")
             (xmlns . "jabber:client")
             (to . ,(jabber-connection-jid jc)))
            (query ((xmlns . "http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info"))
                   (identity ((category . "conference") (type . "text")))
                   (feature ((var . "http://jabber.org/protocol/muc")))
                   (feature ((var . "muc_passwordprotected")))))
   (list nil))
  (jabber-muc-join jc group nickname t))
```

I brought these issues to the attention of the Slack team in March 2014.

Comment: When I invoke `jabber-join-slack-room`, it returns a result `member` for every member on the team, as well as `member@name.xmpp.slack.com`. None of the rooms appear in the result list.

Comment: Right, you'll have to type in `roomname@conference.name.xmpp.slack.com`. Not sure if there's a way to get tab completion for existing rooms...

Comment: That works great, thanks very much!

Answer (score 2):

It's a bug.

I've [raised a ticket](https://sourceforge.net/p/emacs-jabber/bugs/91/) on jabber.el, and notified Slack of the problem.  Their first tier support has escalated it; hopefully it'll be fixed soon.